# Updating data in MS Access DB using JTextField

Tags: java, ms-access, sql-update, jtextfield

I'm trying to use JTextField to update content of my DB, I have a frame where is all information about specific record, then I input correct or changed data to all JTextFields, and then I try to execute UPDATE statement with preparedStatement, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying this way:

```
.....
try {
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String Base = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=DATABASE.mdb";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Base,"","");
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("update table_name SET table_item1='?', table_item2='?', table_item3='?', table_item4='?', table_item5=?, table_item6=?, table_item7=? WHERE table_item8=?");
pst.setString(1, tf1.getText());
pst.setString(2, tf2.getText());
pst.setString(3, tf3.getText());
pst.setString(4, tf4.getText());
pst.setString(5, tf5.getText());
pst.setString(6, tf6.getText());
pst.setString(7, tf7.getText());
pst.setString(8, comboItem.getSelectedItem());
int res= pst.excecuteUpdate();
pst.close();
con.close();
......
```

In the query I use **' '** because it is a String component, I get error at *pst.setString(5, tf5.getText());* maybe because it's Integer values starts there, thats just a hunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use single quotes (') in prepared statement for string fields and correct 'update' query :

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("update table table_name SET table_item1='?'
```

remove '' from all '?' like this for all **string** fields :

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("update table table_name SET table_item1=?,
```

So correct query becomes :

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("update table table_name SET table_item1=?, table_item2=?, table_item3=?, table_item4=?, table_item5=?, table_item6=?, table_item7=? WHERE table_item8=?");
```

Comment: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '**Pa_RaM000**'.
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)

Comment: hey correct query is like 'update table table_name set...' correct it

Comment: and still new error apears [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Comment: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement.
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)

Comment: Show me errors and by the way you have to copy just the last query in your code.

Comment: check table_name contains all fields that you have written in querry.

Comment: Copy this only : PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("update table table_name SET table_item1=?, table_item2=?, table_item3=?, table_item4=?, table_item5=?, table_item6=?, table_item7=? WHERE table_item8=?"); and replace with your preparedstatement.

Comment: I removed *update **table** table_name* and it works, thank you